# How to run (exe) Android OpenGL ES 2.0 on desktop?

Tags: android, opengl-es, desktop

I like to develop an app for android targeting Android 2.2 with OpenGL ES 2.0 Using NDK.
I would like to be able to test and run/compile the code in Desktop first and then port it to Android. What should be my toolchain for this? which framework gives me the ability to use OpenGL ES 2.0 on the Desktop? (not emulator)

Answer (score 1):

For Linux

Ubuntu 11.04/11.11:

```
sudo apt-get install make gcc libgles2-mesa-dev
```

Fedora 15:

```
su -c "yum install make gcc mesa-libGLES-devel mesa-libEGL-devel"
```

Note that you will need superuser rights for the environment you are operating in.

For Windows you can use VS2005 and AMD's Emulator available below (though its not being developed actively on)
http://www.opengles-book.com/ESEmulator.2009-04-28-v1.4.APRIL_2009_RELEASE.msi